# How to convert Nginx.conf configuration to nginx-ingress-controller ingress.yml?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have nginx.conf with following configuration.

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_connect_timeout   65;
proxy_send_timeout      65;
proxy_read_timeout      300;
proxy_buffers           4 256k;
proxy_buffer_size       128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
large_client_header_buffers  8 64k;
client_header_buffer_size    64k;
client_max_body_size    1024m;

server {
        listen          443 ssl;
        server_name server1.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server1.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server1.com.key;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

        rewrite_log on;

        proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        location / {
                location = /robots.txt {
                    add_header  Content-Type  text/plain;
                    return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
                }

                location ~ ^/(files/app)  {
                    proxy_pass http://server1.com:31111;
                }

                proxy_pass https://server2.com;
        }
}
```

I would like to shift my nginx config to kubernetes ingress-nginx ingress.yml. Is there a way to implement this config using kubernetes Ingress resources?

This is my ingress.yml which ofcourse isnt working and hitting the url https://server1.com/files/app goes into multiple redirections and throwing 502 Bad Gateway in the end.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-service
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/my-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: server1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 31111
        path: /files/app
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: @kkopczak It's K8s 1.21 and on cloudprovider. Also note that all other ingress rules work fine except this one. I suspect this is something related to reverse proxy or SSL certificate...but I don't know how to convert this nginx.conf into ingress.yml for Kubernetes.

Comment: Sorry for late response. What is happening if you change port from `listen          443 ssl;` to `listen          31111 ssl;` in nginx.conf?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was removing entries from httpd.conf. my service was directly bypassing the request but I had provided these entries in httpd conf as well due to which it was looping internally. As far as ingress rule is concerned. Above configuration worked fine after i removed related rules from httpd.conf.